I'm looking for the name of this drama about two sisters, one of them being very sick
So around 10 years ago I watched this movie on the TV. I think it is from this century because it didn't look that old (it was in color, not B&W). I don't remember much about it but it's a very sad movie;
It's about two sisters (one of them a young adult and the other one a teenager), both of them caucasian (the younger sister has short hair) who move to a new city by their own. However the younger sister is very sick (she's always coughing throughout the movie as she had some kind of terminal disease related to her lungs) so they struggle to find money and pay the bills. At some point the older sister meets a guy and starts dating him. The guy seems to be very nice and tries to help them.
There's one scene in which they're all at the park making a picnic on the grass, but the activity gets interrupted because the younger sister starts coughing and feeling very bad.
One scene that I remember is at the end when the younger sister is at the hospital, along with her sister and the guy she met. She is lying in the bed and that particular day was her birthday. As a birthday gift, her sister and the other guy covered the whole ceiling of the room with glowing stars (apparently the younger sister's dream was to fly to space or something like that). They turned off the lights, and the girl looked excited at the stars, but then she has like an attack and dies. After that scene I think there is a flashback of both sisters at the beach, and then the credits.
P.S. The movie was dubbed to Spanish when I saw it so I don't know what the original language was, but I guess it was English.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Thank you, I just edited it and added more information

That almost sounds like My Sister's Keeper (2009), but the details are a little different: the older sister has leukemia and the younger sister is expected to be the donor (blood, organs, etc.) to the older sister. If this is the correct movie, I'll create an answer for it.

It's not :( The movie I'm talking about it's probably a bit older and the actors that participated in were not that famous. It almost looked like a low-budget movie
